# ThreadPoolExecutor to create new threads until the desired result is obtained?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create new threads as long as some condition is met, in this example - as long as the `result` variable is less than the `target` variable.  How can I achieve this?

```python
import concurrent.futures
import threading
import time
import uuid


lock = threading.Lock()

target = 20
result = 0


def main(uid: str) -> bool:
    global result
    print(f'Start - {uid}')
    time.sleep(2.0)
    lock.acquire()
    result += 1
    lock.release()
    print(f'Stop - {uid}')
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        while result < target:
            future = executor.submit(main, str(uuid.uuid4()))
```

Please help me figure this out!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your problem? It looks like this case is really simple, hence using threads would be counter-productive. What is it you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @WArnold I need to create new threads until result < target, but in this case (my example) - they don't stop

Comment: They stop, eventually. Try with `time.sleep(0.01)`. While `main` is sleeping the `while`-loop rapidly spawns loads of new threads: is that really what you want?